# onPageFinished not firing correctly when rendering web page

Tags: java, android, webkit

For some reason the onPageFinished is firing before the WebView has finished loading - I can't figure out why...

```
public class WebViewClientTest extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  
        @Override  
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(webview, url);
            webview.scrollTo(0, 500);
        }  
    });
    webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=lala");

}
}
```

---

OK, well it looks like this isn't fixed. I think there's a race condition going on when loading the page, but can't get a reproducible behaviour.

I'm storing the HTML content of a webpage in a SQLite database for viewing when offline. I reload the content into the WebView with:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("fake://fake.com/", htmlBody, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

It seems that sometimes when the WebView loads it fires the WebViewClient.onPageFinished() method correctly, and other times it does not. Sometimes it appears to fire before the page has finished loading, producing a contentHeight of 0 and ignoring any scrollTo calls.

Anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had a project that had code which needed to run only after the webview had displayed it's content, and like you, onPageFinished() wasn't working.  It fired too quickly, before the webview had actually rendered the page.

Instead, I had to use a "PictureListener" which gets fired when the webview actually updates the screen.

You use it like so:

```
mWebView.setPictureListener(new MyPictureListener());
//... and then later on....
class MyPictureListener implements PictureListener {

    @Override
    public void onNewPicture(WebView view, Picture arg1) {
      // put code here that needs to run when the page has finished loading and
      // a new "picture" is on the webview.      
    }    
}
```

Comment: Perfect - thanks! Just want to add that this onNewPicture fires even after a scroll event has finished, so I needed to code around this, but the above works perfectly.

Comment: except this is now deprecated (tablet hel- er - heaven) :(
So I use a javascript call which bests the WebChromeClient onProgressChanged() in terms of return time...  Just have to take care which Thread you are operating in when you get the return (I use the WebView's Handler with a delayed call) -- all that being said, I amd going to see how well WebChromeClient.onProgressChanged() performs

Comment: is there a better way to do this

Comment: @Dan Can you elaborate on your Javascript call? A code snippet would be super. Thanks and +1 in the meanwhile.

Comment: Well, when I tried this, the application ask me that which application would you like to use for this web site "chrome" or "internet". It means, your solution opens external browser. At least, for me..

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem to dismiss my progressdialog when rendering my web page. I solved with onPageStarted.
I hope this solution can help you.

```
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        progressBar.dismiss();

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url,
            android.graphics.Bitmap favicon) {

        if (!progressBar.isShowing()) {
            progressBar.show();
        }
    };
```

Comment: This one works for me. I have a webview that override Url loading.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, well if I make my own private class, it works...

```
private class ViewStoryWebViewClient extends WebViewClient { 
    @Override  
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(webView, url);
        webView.scrollTo(0, 50);
    }  
}
```

Comment: this happens too soon, before the picture is rendered

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the exact same thing with `loadDataWithBaseURL()`.  Sometimes the contents don't show up and the contentHeight is 0.  The odd thing is that clicking anywhere in the web view will cause the contents to show.  Also, if you call `zoomIn();zoomOut();` in the `onPageFinished()` method, the page will appear.

EDIT: The problem with my code is that the HTML content had a dummy window.location= assignment in the onload event, and this was causing the original content not to load at random times.  Sorry, I don't think this is related to what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I was literally looking for an answer for the past 6 hours and finally found one that works for me at least, and it is a simple answer. A timer.
After your OnPageFinished start a timer for as long as you want, in my case I did it for 2 seconds. This will be enough time for the webview to render and load the entire page.
Make sure you run the timer on the UI thread if you want to call a webview method

```
      Timer myTimer = new Timer(); //global variable

      public void startTimer(TimerTask t){
          myTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(t,2000,2000);
      }


           ....
              public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {                          
                  TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
                      @Override
                      public void run() {
                        //stuff to do after page is fully loaded
                        myTimer.cancel();
                      }
                  };
                  startTimer(task);
              }
```

By the way, this is my first answer on stackoverflow. Hope this helps someone!