# How to setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) to a webView AFTER its loaded its contents?

Tags: android, android-webview

In my app there is an advertising web view, that is calling an url when the activity starts.
Everything is nice except one minor thing, it is more like a visibility issue...
So the thing is when i start the activity i literally see the page loading.. About in 0,3 seconds the texts appear then the pictures, and all the content somehow floating in from left to right. It not so nice, i would like to set the visibility of my webView to VIEW.GONE until it is done with the loading, and after that i could set it VISIBLE...

Is there a good, and working way for achieve this?
It is important that **it is must work on Android 2.3 to 4.0 in each and every OS version.**

I already **tried onPageFinished and PictureListener** [**related to this stack question here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702627/onpagefinished-not-firing-correctly-when-rendering-web-page), but no hope, onPageFinished only works properly on 4.0 and PictureListener is for pictures which is not the best way to do this in case of different advertisings with different number of pictures. (and what if there is no picture at all...)

Please if you know a way let know with me. Thanks all.

Comment: Rather than doing this why dont you keep progress dialog in your activity,dismiss when webview loads data completely

Answer (score 2):

have you tried `WebChromeClient` ?

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
        if (progress == 100) {
            // dismisses the PD
            dismissLoadingDialog();
        }
    }
});
    webView.loadUrl("your-Url");
// show message dialog here
createLoadingDialog();
```

i have used this on 2.3 to 4.0 OSes without any issue

Comment: Same results. I want to completly hide my webView until it is DONE with content loading...

Comment: There's no escaping the dependency on either onPageFinished()/onProgressChanged() methods in order to determine the progress of page loading. But coming to the second issue of visibility, a possible workaround would be to place the webview inside another parent view element and utilize the webView.getParent().setVisibility() method.

Answer (score 1):

Use webview visibility during  onPageFinished method
view not display util all page loading.

```
webView1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

                                                @Override
                                                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                                                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                                                    webView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                                }
```