# android webview's onPageFinished is invoked before redirecting to a second page

Tags: android, authentication

Novice to android development I'm trying to apply the web authentication method described here: https://sites.google.com/site/oauthgoog/oauth-practices/mobile-apps-for-complex-login-systems/samplecode

The following is the result code:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        WebView webview = new WebView(this);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            // Show loading progress in activity's title bar.
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                setProgress(progress * 100);
            }
        });

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            // When start to load page, show url in activity's title bar
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url,
                    Bitmap favicon) {
                setTitle(url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
                // Get the cookie from cookie jar.
                String cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                if (cookie == null) {
                    return;
                }
                // Cookie is a string like NAME=VALUE [; NAME=VALUE]
                String[] pairs = cookie.split(";");
                for (int i = 0; i < pairs.length; ++i) {
                    String[] parts = pairs[i].split("=", 2);
                    // If token is found, return it to the calling activity.
                    parts[0] = parts[0].trim();
                    if (parts.length == 2 && parts[0].equalsIgnoreCase("MY_PRIVATE_TOKEN")) {
                        Intent result = new Intent();
                        result.putExtra("token", parts[1]);
                        setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        String queryStringAndroidId = "?aid="+Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID);


        setContentView(webview);

        String urlToLoginPage =getString(R.string.web_login_page).concat(queryStringAndroidId);

        webview.loadUrl(urlToLoginPage);

    }

}
```

my problem is with the **onPageFinished** method. When the webview is displayed for the first time this method is called, which i didn't expect. If the authentication cookie is already present then the activity is immediately being closed. To my understanding this method is supposed to be called only when another page is displayed in the webview (other then the first one that I call), am I wrong about it? can someone shed some light on this behavior? thanks a lot.

BTW, I saw this solution: [onPageFinished not firing correctly when rendering web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702627/onpagefinished-not-firing-correctly-when-rendering-web-page) but I don't like go-around like this. I rather understand why is the method firing when I don't expect it to. Thanks.